# Google Charts allow you to scroll horizontally?

Tags: html, scroll, scrollview, google-visualization

Given this screenshot of a Google Chart, let's say that the width stays fixed, but the years go out to 2030.

[image]

Does Google Charts allow you to scroll horizontally so that all years can be viewed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I can recall it correct, these charts are images..
so if you add that image and put it in a fixed width DIV with overfow-x. this should work.

Comment: The interactivity (clicking each data point to view details) sucks if overflow-x is used. Still looking for a better solution...